# CSV read/write using regex re.sub

Tags: python, regex, csv

I'd like to read a CSV file and recompile using:

```
re.sub('\s+(STREET|ST|TRAIL|TRL|TR)\s*$', '', test_file, flags=re.M)
```

I'm getting:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

When using:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("some.csv", "rb"))
for row in reader:
    print row

import csv
writer = csv.writer(open("some.csv", "wb"))
writer.writerows(someiterable)
```

Looks like I need a function.  Anyone have some sugestions?

Comment: Are you getting the error when you run the first bit of code, or the last bit of code? Is the first bit of code ever run, or has your program not gotten there yet, and even when the last bit of code is all there is, you still get that error? If your first bit of code *is* run, please show at what point in the last bit of code that happens.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a string to `re.sub()` third argument, which can be a line of your `reader` object. You can already pass to `writer` the iterable that will do the substitutions:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("input.csv", "rb"))
writer = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb"))
test = '\s+(STREET|ST|TRAIL|TRL|TR)\s*$'
writer.writerows( (re.sub(test, '', line[0], flags=re.M) for line in reader) )
```

Comment: My re module returns:  _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)  I'm still geting the expected string or buffer TypeError.

Comment: try to remove `flag=re.M`

Comment: Still the same. test = str('\s+(STREET|ST|TRAIL|TRL|TR)\s*$') didn't work either.

Comment: I think this is not iterating through every line and looking for a match

Comment: I will take a look at this later... Could you make available one testing case in Dropbox or somewhere else?

Comment: "OID_","LastModifi","City","StreetName","HouseNumbe"
,"5/21/2013 0:00:00","Enid","COYOTE TRAIL",3729.000000
,"5/21/2013 0:00:00","Enid","COUNTRY CLUB DR",4023.000000

Comment: OID_ LastModifi City StreetName HouseNumbe
 5/21/2013 0:00:00 Enid COYOTE TRAIL 3729.000000
 5/21/2013 0:00:00 Enid COUNTRY CLUB DR 4023.000000
 5/21/2013 0:00:00 Enid PATRICK HENRY PL 4222.000000

Comment: The TypeError is gone.  However the code is not writing. I'll keep plugging away!